# Python module organization to make import statement cleaner

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have a directory B inside directory A, which resides in a directory included in `PYTHONPATH`.

Now lets say that within directory B i have files - B_file_1.py, B_file_2.py, with each file defining a single function (i.e. B_file_1.py defines `B_file_1`).

I want to use this collection of files as a python package. But now when I want to use the method `B_file_1`, I have to write this long statement:

```
from A.B.B_file_1 import B_file_1
```

What I would like is to have the convenience of simply writing this instead, (while maintaing the directory and file setup I currently have):

```
from A.B import B_file_1
```

Is there any python module hack to do this?

Comment: Yes, but you should ask yourself what the advantage is of making a a directory and two files just to hold two functions.

Comment: @BrenBarn I am using an example to frame my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in `A/B/__init__.py`:

```
from B_file_1 import B_file_1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can import your modules inside of the `__init__.py` file in the `B` folder:

**`__init__.py`**:

```
__all__ = ('B_file_1',)

from B_file_1 import B_file_1
```

Now, your second import statement will work.

Comment: Blender, you answered just a couple of seconds behind millerdev so I chose his answer as correct!